# Why is my reduce() function in javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, reduce

arr is an array of customers with different phone plans, but I dont know why my reduce function isn't working to add up my numOfLines. e.g.

```
arr=[{
    customer: {
      whatPlan: "no contract",
      monthlyCost: 50,
      tax:0.4
    },
    monthlyFee:1,
    numOfLines:1
  }..........]

console.log(arr.reduce((total, item)=>{return total + item.numOfLines;}));
```

Can someone help me regarding this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Sigh.* Yet another victim of the over-complex `reduce` function being hyped by all and sundry. Unless you're doing functional programming with predefined reducers, just don't use `reduce`. Use a loop. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to be fair. What he wrote was just sum. Hardly an "over-complex" use of the reduce function.

Comment: @Olian04 - I'm not saying the *use* is complex. I'm saying `reduce` is, even for its headline use case (sums). The mistake above is perfectly understandable and an exemplar of why `reduce` just isn't for people not doing FP. The OP wouldn't have made that mistake with a simple loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ahh, my bad.

Comment: @Olian04- Thanks for flagging it. I wouldn't have wanted the OP to read it that same way. :-) So thanks for the chance to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.reduce((total, item)=>{return total + item.numOfLines},0);
```

You need to add "0" to make it work

Comment: I did that but this is what I  
'[object Object]3421 0' as my output, I dont know what im doing wrong here.

Comment: @Ishasharmax - If you've done that, you won't get that output. Double-check you have it in the place shown (here, and in the answers to the other question).